# git commit history lost?

Tags: git, gitlab

I encountered the following problem：

```
    $ git show 0fb108b
    commit 0fb108b3e564f92e60a14d4da6ab1df32e67a35f
    Author: user1 <user1@example.com>
    Date:   Thu Apr 16 10:08:01 2015 +0800

        update commiit

    diff --git a/file1.jsp
    index a6183b1..b07cd04 100644
    ...
    ...
```

But when I submitted the query history of this file, and didn't see the above submit history:

```
    $ git log -- file1.jsp
    ...
    ...
```

gitlab version: gitlab-7.7.2_omnibus.5.4.2.ci x86_64
git version:    git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0 OR Eclipse subgit-2.0.3
OS version:     CentOS 7.0 64bit

How to solve this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: That commit probably isn't in the current branch.

Comment: no,I am sure to work in the same branch

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do it is this:

```
git log --follow -p -- file1.jsp
```

Comment: Thanks! Why github see this history?

Comment: Of course. github only "hosting" your files. once you clone it you have all locally on your machine.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, Why github not see this commit history?

Comment: I don't understand. you have pushed your changes to github and you don't see them? if you did not pushed them they are only local changes ofcourse

Comment: yes, I've pushed to Gitlab, but some can not see committed, Why?

Comment: When you do `git --no-pager log --oneline -n 25` you don't see your commits? that's what yo trying to say?